# Add an Object to Entity Framework using a navigational property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

Hi I use C# and EF 4.

I have two Entities `CmsContent` and `CmsJob`.
`CmsJob` has a *navigational property* to `CmsContent`.

I need add a `CmsContent` Object to `CmsJob` using the navigational property.

My code run with no error but I cannot persist the new entry om DataBase.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Please provide me an example of code. Thanks for your support!

```
       using (CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
        {
            CmsContent myContent = context.CmsContents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentId == contentId);
            CmsJob myJob = context.CmsJobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.JobId == jobId);
            myJob.CmsContents.Add(myContent);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments under @Hasan's answer you have incorrectly defined database. Your Job and Content are in many-to-many relation so you have junction table called `CmsJobsContents` but this table is missing primary key. Because of that it is read-only for EF and you cannot create new relations in your application. You must go to your database and mark both FKs in the `CmsJobsContents` as primary keys. After that update your model from database and you should be able to save changes.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav Mrnka, I understand now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't saved changes. Try this:

```
using (CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
    {
        CmsContent myContent = context.CmsContents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentId == contentId);
        CmsJob myJob = context.CmsJobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.JobId == jobId);
        myJob.CmsContents.Add(myContent);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: I get his error with your code: Unable to update the EntitySet 'CmsJobsContents' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.

Comment: @GibboK.What is this CmsJobsContents table? Is it a junction table?

Comment: This is because the junction table, which used for the many-to-many relation between CmsContents and CmsJobs,is not updated. Make the keys of both the tables a composite key in the CmsJobsContents table. Hopefully this would resolve the issue